# How is the moon's orbital motion accounted for in determining the best observation platform/location for JWST at L2?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mission-design, lagrangian-points, james-webb-telescope, halo-orbit

The moon's periodic motion would appear to impose a perturbation to the otherwise equilibrium state of the solar/earth L2 point.

Comment: Welcome to Space SE, it's a really interesting question! The Moon and Earth orbit around their center of mass and are relatively close to each other compared to the distance to Sun-Earth L2, so to first order in potential they look like a single object. But to higher order they do look like a wiggling object. Remember though that JWST is in a giant halo orbit about L2. It's not near the L2 point but instead moves around a big tilted oval roughly 400,000 to 800,000 km from L2 as shown in the plots at the bottom of [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23249/12102)

Comment: Also remember that the Earth-Moon system are in a slightly elliptical orbit around the Sun, so that's a second perturbation that might even be larger than the Earth-Moon effect.

Comment: The moon orbits Earth 6 times for each time the JWST orbits around L2, so it is really a very short-term cyclic perturbation, and will tend to cancel out its own effects. The harmonic with the bi-yearly cycle of the Halo orbit is exactly what makes *that* halo orbit more stable than loafing around at the L2 point itself.